# SQL Distinct not working in inner join

Tags: sql, inner-join, distinct

I am joining two tables "tblQuestion" and "tblSubskill", i need distinct SubSkillName in result as shown in query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ss.SubSkillName , ss.SkillId , ss.Id As SubSkillId 
FROM dbo.tblQuestion AS q INNER JOIN
dbo.tblSubSkill AS ss ON q.SubSkillId = ss.Id
```

which is working fine untill i add a column from tblQuestion and returns

[image]

now i want to add a column from tblQuestion as well so query is as follow

```
SELECT DISTINCT ss.SubSkillName , ss.SkillId , ss.Id As SubSkillId , q.EadLevel
 FROM dbo.tblQuestion AS q INNER JOIN
 dbo.tblSubSkill AS ss ON q.SubSkillId = ss.Id
```

but what it returns have not distinct SubSkillName as below

[image]

Comment: Well the `EadLevel` for both rows is different so there are 2 distinct rows so you get 2 rows.  If you only want one row you need to decide which `EadLevel` you want and express that condition in your query.

Comment: Distinct is working as aspected, EadLevel is different for two records.... You can use **Group By** clause in place of Distinct...

Comment: `DISTINCT` keeps only distinct **records**. So your second screenshot shows your query working properly. What would you want to see as a result if not that?

Comment: What do you want it to return?  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: @AlexK.Thank you i got your point. simply apply where clause to get desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as i observed Distinct keyword is working fine as it judges the difference between two or more rows on the basis of all columns including and since for 1st two rows EadLevel is different which makes the entire combination different from one another. So It's working fine.
However if you want only one of them then you have to decide which EadLevel you want to show.